# Amcharts Inherit Font or set all Element Font

Tags: jquery, css, fonts, amcharts

I've set my page css to:

```
html { 
    font-family: 'Not the Default AmCharts Font';
}
```

I haven't specified a font in my chart code, but the charts are not inheriting the page's css defined font.

Is there a way to globally set the font for all Amcharts elements in one go?
Something like:

```
AmCharts.defaultFontFamily = 'Not the Default AmCharts Font';
```

I'd also be happy with some sort of jQuery solution like:

```
$('.amcharts').find('*').css('font-family', 'Not the Default AmCharts Font');
```

Neither of these solutions are working.

I'd really like this to impact at least the following:
Chart Title
, Axes Titles
, Axes Labels
, Graph Labels
, Balloon Text
, Legend Labels
, Legend Values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since AmCharts uses inline styles and attributes, you'll likely need to use `!important` to override the fonts

```
.yourchartclass * {
  font-family: 'Impact' !important;
}
```

Another way to go about this is to leverage the [`AmCharts.addInitHandler`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmCharts#addInitHandler) method to create a global `init` listener that runs on as many types of charts as you want and sets the [`fontFamily`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#fontFamily) and other properties during initialization. For example:

```
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(chart) {
  chart.fontFamily = 'Oswald';
  chart.fontSize = 16;
});
```

You can also specify an array of chart types to limit what the initHandler can run on. You can also add custom flags to your chart object and use them to determine which settings you want to set, for example:

```
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(chart) {
  if (chart.useLato) {
    chart.fontFamily = "Lato";
    chart.fontSize = 16;
  } else if (chart.useRoboto) {
    chart.fontFamily = "Roboto";
    chart.fontSize = 12;
  } else {
    chart.fontFamily = "Oswald";
    chart.fontSize = 12;
  }
});
```

Here's a [demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/b50837dde974f06c042ac0e5a89ae9f1?editors=0010) of this in action.

Comment: Fantastic! I had already tried the `!important` css override, which didn't work, but the init handler was perfect.

Comment: Strange, `!important` worked for me while I was experimenting with the codepen. You can also refer to the list of [CSS class names](http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/css-class-names/) generated by the charts (you'll need to set `addClassNames` to true) and go that route to style the text elements directly if you prefer doing it through CSS.