# Change all the font colors in amStockChart dynamically after the chart is drawn

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amstock

I have a website where I am using amStockCharts. The problem is that when I turn on the dark theme of the website, all the labels of amCharts: legends, date time range, zoom levels, etc hide in the black background because of black font.

How can I change the charts font color dynamically instead of changing it from javascript for all the classes with text in them?

This is different from [Amcharts Inherit Font or set all Element Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45923814/amcharts-inherit-font-or-set-all-element-font) as I want to change the color **after** chart is drawn and so I cannot set it in config or init methods.

AmChart seem to be using inline styles and hence not inheriting my color property set to #fff in super elements (even after `!important`). Here is what I can see when I make my background dark:

[image]

Comment: Please post enough of your ("*[mcve]*") code that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @DavidThomas, There is nothing more I can say for this as pasting the config for chart here will be useless and won't add any value to the question. I guess you haven't worked with amcharts before. A verifiable example here would be any amStockChart of your wish. Still, I have included the screenshot  and some more info for my example so that you can understand better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rightly said that amCharts does use inline styles. I encountered the same problem some time back and used the below css: (lightsOff is a class to my body tag in below eg., & chartdiv the div for drawing the chart as given by amCharts)

```
.lightsOff #chartdiv text, .lightsOff #chartdiv input, .lightsOff .amChartsPeriodSelector {
    color: #fff !important;
    fill: #fff !important;
}
```

Though this is not what you are exactly asking for, as I assume you are asking for some method or changing the charts property value and validating the chart again, but this one maybe simpler than that.

Comment: great. This one will indeed be easier.